# jquery click to show div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a php page that will parse some data and end up with an array of data.  I want to put each key in its own div so a user can click on a seperate navigation panel and the proper div will display.

```
 $array = array('userId'=>'bob1','firstName'=>'bob','lastName'=>'Jones');
```

I have a little jquery that handles clicking.

```
 $('.nav').click(function()
  {
            $('.userModule').hide();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#'+id).show();
 });
```

so i interate through and set all the fields as so:

```
  $data = "";
  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {
      $data .= "<div id='" . $key . "' class='userModule'>";
      $data .= $key . "," . $value;
      $data .= "</div>";
    $navMenu[] = $key;
   }
```

and my little nav panel:

```
 echo "<div id='navMenu'>\n";
 foreach ($navMenu as $v)
 {
    echo "<a href='#' id='" . $v . "' class='nav'>" . $v . "</a><br>\n";
 }
 echo "</div>\n";
```

and then:

```
 echo $data;
```

i do this, because I want the nav menu to be on left and the divs to be in the middle.  I do that by setting css navMenu:

```
 #navMenu{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
  }
  .userModule{
    float:left;
  }
```

the problem i am having is if i click on a link nothing happens.   I can solve this by echo'ing the data in the foreach loop instaed of setting it to $data.  the problem with that is that the nav menu will not be to the left the data....

Comment: before foreach loop try var_dump or print_r the $navMenu in order to see what you get in array finally?

Comment: the navMenu array looks fine because i see each anchor for each key.

Comment: same ID in the "navMenu" and in the "userModule" ?

Comment: if you want the navMenu to be on the left, print it first. Also check your console for any js errors and ensure that our jquery code is wrapped under ready function and keep in mind that the id attribute is meant to be unique

Comment: yea mama, i did alert just to make sure, and ids are exact.  Nou, i derive the navmenu from the foreach loop so i cant print it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not good to use id more than once.
try this:

html :

```
<a href='#' data-id='" . $v . "' class='nav'>" . $v . "</a>
```

js:

```
$('body').on('click', '.nav',  function() {
    $('.userModule').hide();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#'+id).show();
});
```

Comment: When he is using it in a loop, id can change.

Comment: The id's will never be the same because the keys in the array are unique.  however, this did get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Generally as far as I have seen the code that is from the php will not have any effect from the script called from outside. So try using onclick in the anchor and try running it.

Like `<a href="#" onclick="sample (this);"></a>`

```
function sample (id) {
// Now do whatever here.

return false; // To prevent default action.
}
```

Comment: same result here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function jQuery.

This binds the event to the element for now and the future.

```
$('body').delegate('.nav', 'click', function() {
    $('.userModule').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+id).show();
});
```

Comment: I tried that and no change.  I know the event is firing because as a test i added alert(id) and it showed as expected...